# How can I logout of and then log back into Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I bought an app and then later couldn't remember my password and the reset option didn't work so I ended up creating a second account. (Guess that was dumb of me.)
Anyway, is there a way I can log out and then back in with my original account?

Answer (score 1):

I have not actually tested this, but I think it should work in theory.

1. Open the **Ubuntu Software Center** application.
2. Click on the **File** menu and click on **Reinstall Previous Purchases**.
3. Logon with your original account and you setup and you should be able to install the original applications that you purchased.