# How do I logout of Ubuntu Software Center? (Seriously, where's the logout button?)

Tags: software-center

I'm messing around with syncing software between computers using Software Center.  I want to change what user I am logged into Ubuntu Software Center.  (Simple enough, right?)

I cannot figure out how to logout of my Software Center account so I can login with a different one.

The best advice I could find was this:
[How can I logout of and then log back into Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59131/how-can-i-logout-of-and-then-log-back-into-ubuntu-software-center)

It didn't help at all.  Am I missing something really obvious, or is there really no "logout" button anywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that newer versions of Ubuntu (eg 21.10) don't use "Ubuntu Software Center" any more but use Snap store, which is also named "Ubuntu Software".

Answer (score 4):

You can delete stored Software Center tokens from "Password and Keys" and then log in again.

Answer (score 0):

> What is Ubuntu Software Center?
>
> Ubuntu Software Center (USC) is an application that allows you to
>   obtain, install, and remove software in a single window.  With USC,
>   you can manage all of your software needs without ever having to
>   launch an Internet browser or wonder whether the software you download
>   is safe and compatible with your operating system.

<sup>Source: https://courtneyloo.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/ubuntu-software-center-streamline-your-software-experience/</sup>

You can't logout of USC.  The link that you mentioned, talks about logging out of the machine.  So to login with other user credential, just log out from the current user, and logging with the new one.

Comment: This doesn't address his issue and he may need to file a bug on this. I too have logged into the Ubuntu Software Center only to realise I am using someone elses desktop session. Even rebooting the machine has no effect. They are now free to comment using my name as well as download my previous purchase. Not only can I not log out, but I also cannot log in a new user - even if I were to create a launchpad account for them.

Comment: @mitch although correct he is talking about the comments made to software. You need to log in for that but you can not exit that login. So 2 people on the same machine can comment with the same name.